# CSS on a Component

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I want to know what I should write and where in Architect to have some CSS do the following

What I have
[image]

What I want
[image: Vin and Source centered]

Comment: Can u post a mockup of what exactly you're trying to get?

Comment: Added Visual exemple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think I would like that kind of alignment especially if you have more than 1 row of fields in your form (it would look ugly).

Looks like standard `labelAlign` property doesn't support `center`, so you would need to use `labelCls`.

Take a look at fiddle: http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/3qOhD/

Comment: Thank you. Pretty sure it work but I don't know how to use that in sencha Architect.. has if I write anything he will overide. I'll try to find how to add this css ressource in my project and if I do will add the answer + accept yours

Comment: my problem is 'linking' the css resource atm, if i link it manually, sencha will overide it every time.

I dont want to modify Sencha's css has it huge and i dont understand most that is going on in it

Comment: Yes. You want to add your own CSS file.

Comment: index.html and app.html are auto generated, so I can't manually link it

Comment: It worked, had issues with ref of the css, now it does work thank!